# GCM:Device can send message but not registered

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, android-asynctask, google-cloud-messaging

Im currently making an android app based on gcm.When i run on real device,it has not shown any error and i can send messages(GAE logs also shows /send statement).The problem is another device didnt receive any messages.I refer to GAE logs and it doest show any /register statement.When i run on emulator,i will get this error.

```
04-12 14:56:38.897: E/AndroidRuntime(1181): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
04-12 14:56:38.897: E/AndroidRuntime(1181):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
04-12 14:56:38.897: E/AndroidRuntime(1181):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
04-12 14:56:38.897: E/AndroidRuntime(1181):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
04-12 14:56:38.897: E/AndroidRuntime(1181):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
04-12 14:56:38.897: E/AndroidRuntime(1181):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
04-12 14:56:38.897: E/AndroidRuntime(1181):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
04-12 14:56:38.897: E/AndroidRuntime(1181):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
04-12 14:56:38.897: E/AndroidRuntime(1181):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
04-12 14:56:38.897: E/AndroidRuntime(1181): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-12 14:56:38.897: E/AndroidRuntime(1181):     at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging.register(Unknown Source)
04-12 14:56:38.897: E/AndroidRuntime(1181):     at com.example.gcm.GcmUtil$1.doInBackground(GcmUtil.java:142)
04-12 14:56:38.897: E/AndroidRuntime(1181):     at com.example.gcm.GcmUtil$1.doInBackground(GcmUtil.java:1)
04-12 14:56:38.897: E/AndroidRuntime(1181):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
04-12 14:56:38.897: E/AndroidRuntime(1181):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
04-12 14:56:38.897: E/AndroidRuntime(1181):     ... 4 more
```

The code is :

```
  private void registerBackground() {
    registrationTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            long backoff = BACKOFF_MILLI_SECONDS + random.nextInt(1000);
            for (int i = 1; i <= MAX_ATTEMPTS; i++) {
                //Log.d(TAG, "Attempt #" + i + " to register");
                try {
                    if (gcm == null) {
                        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(ctx);
                    }
                    String regid = gcm.register(Common.getSenderId());

                    ServerUtilities.register(Common.getPreferredEmail(),
                    regid);

                    // Save the regid - no need to register again.
                    setRegistrationId(regid);
                    return Boolean.TRUE;

                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    //Log.e(TAG, "Failed to register on attempt " + i + ":"
                    + ex);
                    if (i == MAX_ATTEMPTS) {
                        break;
                    }
                    try {
                        //Log.d(TAG, "Sleeping for " + backoff + " ms before
                        retry");
                        Thread.sleep(backoff);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                        // Activity finished before we complete - exit.
                        //Log.d(TAG, "Thread interrupted: abort remaining
                        retries!");
                        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    }
                    // increase backoff exponentially
                    backoff *= 2;                       
                }
            }
            return Boolean.FALSE;
        }
```

Note: I noticed a horizontal line on register at gcm.register...When i hover to it,its says @RequiresPermission(value="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE")
@Deprecated

I already mentioned the permission in android manifest but still the line didnt gone.

Android Manifest:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.heylo"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<permission
    android:name="com.example.heylo.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.heylo.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" >
</uses-permission>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" >
</uses-permission>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" >
</uses-permission>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" >      
</uses-permission>

<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>

<application
    android:name="com.example.heylo.Common"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_splash"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".SplashScreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.example.gcm.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

            <category android:name="com.example.heylo" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <provider
        android:name="com.example.heylo.DataProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.heylo.provider"
        android:exported="false" >
    </provider>

    <activity
        android:name=".Message_List"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_message__list" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_settings" >
    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you show us the manifest please?

Comment: I have added manifest file,Please take a look..

Comment: Can you show line 142 in GcmUtil.java?

Comment: line 142 is: String regid = gcm.register(Common.getSenderId());

Comment: I have added the gcm listener service to manifest file but still having same error....Could it be because the word register got horizontal line and keep asking permission which already in android manifest...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial you follow is too old. Check message from google developers for your way:

> GCM register() is deprecated starting May 28, 2015. New app development should use the Instance ID API to handle the creation, rotation, and updating of registration tokens.

[Source](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/legacy-regid#registration-state-sync-handling)

So its recommend to follow this guide from google developers:
[Guide](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client)

Regards

Comment: i tried the solution you gave me and still got same error.The code gcm.register() is deprecated which has a horizontal line/struck on it.Is there any way to remove it??